# why css width property is working with input element

Tags: html, css, input, width

According to CSS [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width):

> The width CSS property ... applies to all elements but non-replaced inline elements, table rows, and row groups

Input is inline element. So why *width* property is work with *input* element?

Comment: "**non-replaced** inline elements".

Comment: Kinda spells it out right there. Since inputs are replaced inline elements, width applies to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is for `non-replaced inline elements`. Input is a replaced element.

> Replaced element
>
> In CSS, a replaced element is an element whose representation is
>   outside the scope of CSS. These are kind of external objects whose
>   representation is independent of the CSS. Typical replaced elements
>   are `<img>`, `<object>`, `<video>` or form elements like `<textarea>` and
>   `<input>`. Some elements, like `<audio>` or `<canvas>` are replaced elements
>   only in specific cases. Objects inserted using the CSS content
>   properties are anonymous replaced elements.
>
> CSS handles replaced elements specifically in some cases, like when
>   calculating margins and some auto values.
>
> Note that some replaced elements, but not all, have intrinsic
>   dimensions or a defined baseline, which is used by some CSS properties
>   like vertical-align.

Reference: [MDN - Replaced element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element)